# Projection and direct sum

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, projective-geometry

I want to show that for every projection $A^2=A$ we have that there exists a subspace $U_1 \subset ker(A)$ and $U_2$ such that $A|_{U_2} = id$ such that $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$. Does anybody here have a hint how to show this?

Comment: Some continuity requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: (1) For $x \in V$ we have $x = (x-Ax) + Ax$.

(2) What can you say about $A(x-Ax)$ and $A(Ax)$?

Comment: alright, thanks. but we only have $U_1 = ker(A)$ and $U_2 = im(A)$ if $A$ is an orthogonal projection, right?(as those are self-adjoint)

Comment: No. In case of an orthogonal projection we *moreover* have that $U_1 \perp U_2$, but the sum of $\ker A$ and ${\rm im}\, A$ is direct and equal to $V$ for any projection.

Comment: ah, okay, but that means, that every projection is at least normal?

Comment: No ... exactly orthogonal projections are normal, as normal $\iff$ orthogonal diagonizable and a projection has the eigenspaces $\ker(A)$ (eigenvalue 0) and ${\rm im}\,A$ (eigenvalue 1).

Comment: my reasoning is the following: $V = ker(A) \oplus im(A) = ker(A) \oplus ker(A)^\perp => ker(A)^\perp = im(A) =>ker(A) = ker(A^*) => ||Ax||=||A^*x||=> \text{normal}$

Comment: No. $V_1 \oplus V_2 = V_1 \oplus V_3$ does not imply $V_1 = V_3$. Consider $V_1 = \mathbb R \times \{0\}$, $V_2 = \{0\} \times \mathbb R$ and $V_3 = \{(x,x) \mid x \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: ohhh...thank you...my fault..now is everything clear